# Routers on airplanes

Tags: airlines, regulations

I think this is an okay place to ask this. Let me know if it is not.

In about a month, my school is going on a school trip and the plane ride is going to be around 15 hours. I was think about setting up a small network on the plane so that we can chat on a locally hosted program.

I would do this by bringing a small router and hooking it up.

Is this against the rules of most airlines and do you think I could get in trouble?

Comment: I'm guessing you are considering a wireless router, because even if you are sitting together, Ethernet cords everywhere have their own issues.

Comment: You need to check with the airline. Some airplanes (especially international) have in-inflight wifi, so you should be fine using that. If it doesn't have in-flight wifi, it might not be rated for wifi, in which case the answer is probably no.

Comment: @raptortech97 I'm *hoping* that if they do have in-flight WiFi, it doesn't allow you to directly connect with other devices on that network.

Comment: @fooot yeah I don't know how router security works at all. But isn't there some way it could work? With like..  a VPN I think??

Comment: @raptortech97 software developer here, it is possible (and probable) that the in-flight WiFi does not allow client-to-client connection. In that case you'll need to turn the WiFi connector of your laptop into a router, which isn't that hard really (lookup "netsh wlan start hostednetwork").

Comment: @kevin so does that mean that bringing a wireless router is not breaking the regulations?

Comment: I dunno about the rules, but a WiFi router is technically the same as the WiFi adapter on any laptop : a transmitter + receiver. You just need the software to make it function one way or the other. Laptop is more convenient as you don't need A/C power.